# using insertMany() in mogodb but I couldnt insert it eventhough the syntax is correct

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

db.customers.insertMany(
[

{

"name":"customer1",

"email":"customer1@gmail.com",

"phone":64665656,

"hall_id":100

},

{

"name":"customer2",

"email":"customer2@gmail.com",

"phone":6463155,

"hall_id":200

])

[here is the screen shot of my code and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kp3BU.png)

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: What error are you getting. Update that also in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your didn't close the curly braces properly for the second object

try this, this will work:

```
db.customers.insertMany([
   {
      "name": "customer1",
      "email": "customer1@gmail.com",
      "phone": 64665656,
      "hall_id": 100
   },
   {
      "name": "customer2",
      "email": "customer2@gmail.com",
      "phone": 6463155,
      "hall_id": 200
   }
])
```